# Stuck on fixing this query, mistakes in two commands that I wrote

Tags: sql, database, select, in-clause

```
EMPLOYEE (fname, minit, lname, ssn, birthdate, address, sex, salary, superssn, dno)
KEY: ssn

DEPARTMENT (dname, dnumber, mgrssn, mgrstartdate)
KEY: dnumber.

PROJECT (pname, pnumber, plocation, dnum)
KEY: pnumber.

WORKS_ON (essn, pno, hours)
KEY: (essn, pno)

DEPENDENT (essn, dependent-name, sex, bdate, relationship)
KEY: (essn, dependent-name)
```

So I'm just really confused by how do I add more materials to the select command, let's say add SSN

I want to find the last name and first name of all the managers who is on project number 47:

```
SELECT lname, fname
FROM   employee e, department d
Where d.mgrssn  = e.ssn
WHERE  e.ssn IN (SELECT w.essn
                       FROM   works_on w, project p
                       WHERE  w.pno  = p.pnumber
                                AND     w.pno ='47'
                               );
```

But now I want add ssn to it:

```
SELECT lname, fname, ssn
FROM   employee e, department d
Where d.mgrssn  = e.ssn
WHERE  ssn IN (SELECT w.essn
                       FROM   works_on w, project p
                       WHERE  w.pno  = p.pnumber
                                AND     w.pno ='02'
                               );
```

Comment: (1) What is the problem you're having with your second query? It seems to include the ssn column in the select list. (2) Don't use SSN for a table key, it's a problematic choice.

Comment: can you please write an answer? I promise I will accept it. basically I just want get these two command right, with and without SSN as a criteria

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is.  Are you trying to display the SSN or filter by the SSN?

Comment: sorry I mean for the first command I just want get the lname and fname of managers who is working on project 47, and second command is include social security of manager with last and first name

Comment: The employee table reference `e` holds the manager record and has the ssn (you used it in your join of employee / department tables), so your second query seems correct already.

Comment: the first one? also I just keep getting confused, should I should e.lname or lanme fname etc when using criterias?

Comment: did you solve it already?

Comment: @davejal sorry no can you please write an answer if you can, I will accept it. just keep getting confused by if I want add ssn into my criterias of manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this?

```
select * from employee e,works_on w,department d 
where e.ssn=d.mgrssn and e.ssn=w.essn and w.pno = 47
```

**edit using joins**

```
select * from employee 
join works_on on employee.ssn=works_on.essn 
join department on employee.ssn=department.mgsrssn
wher works_on.pno=47
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Yes - ANSI'92 standard was finalized in **1992** - which now is **23** years ago