# using not in clause the right way in sql, don't know how to select from gender

Tags: sql, database, select, where-clause, notin

```
EMPLOYEE (fmane, minit, lname, ssn, birthdate, address, sex, salary, superssn, dno) KEY: ssn
DEPARTMENT (dname, dnumber, mgrssn, mgrstartdate) KEY: dnumber.
PROJECT  (pname, pnumber, plocation, dnum) KEY: pnumber.
WORKS_ON (essn, pno, hours) KEY: (essn, pno)
DEPENDENT  (essn, dependent-name, sex, bdate, relationship) KEY: (essn, dependent-name)
```

I want to get first and last names and ssn of each female employees with no dependents, but I get stuck at the final command part:

```
select e.lname, e.fname, e.ssn
from employee e
where e.ssn  not in (
select essn
from dependent
)
```

how do I add the gender part?

Comment: `where e.ssn not in ( select essn from dependent ) and e.sex = 'Female'?`

Comment: this looks related to you question http://stackoverflow.com/q/33975601/3664960 is it some kind of exam you guys are making?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, you can combine multiple filters by using the AND keyword.

```
select 
   e.lname, e.fname, e.ssn
from employee e
where e.ssn  not in (
                      select essn
                        from dependent
                     )
    AND e.sex = 'Female'
```

Comment: Thanks! can I put and e.sex before the where e.ssn not in clause?

Comment: @Stevemccain: You can put the clauses in any order. It will not affect the speed of  the query - the database should have a query optimizer that determines how best to apply the filters.

Comment: Thanks! and lastly if I just want the last and first name, not ssn, I know I must the e.ssn from select, but what about the part where e.ssn not in (......; do I change e.ssn to just ssn?

Comment: I've seen in some clause people just use ssn not in or ssn exist, no e. in front of it